# Laravel MultiAuth logged in , but sees me as a Guest

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I created MultiAuth, i can now login with my new admin auth.
But the problem is , he redirects me to the normal login page of Auth because of im a guest. But im also logged in as a admin.

When i login with normal auth, it works as normal,

some code to test :

```
    @guest
        Guest
    @endguest

    @auth('web')
        web
    @endauth
    @auth('admin')
        admin
    @endauth
```

When i login with normal user it shows :

```
Web
```

when i logged out of everything it shows :

```
guest
```

and when i login with admin it shows :

```
guest admin
```

How can i disable/logout the guest when i login with admin?

Comment: You have to separate the LoginControllers for each of your guard and do auth()->guard('web')->logout(); for admin's LoginController and auth()->guard('admin')->logout(); for user's login controller exactly after login is successful.

Comment: In that case if you login with admin you're sure that there's no one logged in with web guard and the same for web login

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad, i have 2 controllers. 1 for normal and 1 for admin.Both controllers use AuthenticatesUsers, in the Controller for admin login i override the showLoginForm and guard functions,

Comment: where should i put  auth()->guard('web')->logout()

Comment: override the sendLoginResponse method too. This method is called when user is logged in successfully.

Comment: I ovverride t showloginform with other view , and guard function with Auth::guard('admin'), with what should i override sendloginresponse

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad i have done this. it doesnt work, still redirected to login page of normal auth and still see "Broker guest"